# DomPDF table fixed column width and break long text

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have a table with very long texts that has no spaces (users like to post a full website URL complete with all the parameters)

Then I set on `word-break:break-all;` and `word-wrap:break-word;` on each `<td>` hoping that the text could fit on the table.

I also set all the `<td>` / column widths to some specified amount.

I use Laravel's DomPDF wrapper here: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

---

**Case 1:** No `table-layout: fixed`

```
<table class="bordered">
    <tr class="font-12">
        <th style="width: 25px">No</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Nama Alat</th>
        <th style="width: 25px">Jml</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">Spesifikasi</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">Supplier</th>
        <th style="width: 150px">Gambar</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($items as $index => $item)
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25px">{{ ($index+1) }}</td>
        <td style="width: 100px">{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
        <td style="width: 25px">{{ $item['jumlah_disetujui'] }}</td>
        <td class="font-12" style="width: 300px; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word;">
            {!! nl2br( $item['spesifikasi'] ) !!}
        </td>
        <td class="font-12" style="width: 300px; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word;">
            {!! nl2br( $item['supplier'] ) !!}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 150px">
            @if ($item['image'])
                <img style="max-height: 125px;" src="{{ $item['image'] }}" />
            @else
                -
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Case 1 PDF Result:**  Word-wrap does not work, column width works on cells with few texts, but does not work either on cells that has long texts (needs word-wrap).

[image: Word-wrap does not work]

---

**Case 2:** Adding `table-layout: fixed`

```
<table class="bordered" style="table-layout: fixed"> <!-- only added this -->
    <tr class="font-12">
        <th style="width: 25px">No</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Nama Alat</th>
        <th style="width: 25px">Jml</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">Spesifikasi</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">Supplier</th>
        <th style="width: 150px">Gambar</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($items as $index => $item)
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25px">{{ ($index+1) }}</td>
        <td style="width: 100px">{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
        <td style="width: 25px">{{ $item['jumlah_disetujui'] }}</td>
        <td class="font-12" style="width: 300px; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word;">
            {!! nl2br( $item['spesifikasi'] ) !!}
        </td>
        <td class="font-12" style="width: 300px; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word;">
            {!! nl2br( $item['supplier'] ) !!}
        </td>
        <td style="width: 150px">
            @if ($item['image'])
                <img style="max-height: 125px;" src="{{ $item['image'] }}" />
            @else
                -
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Case 2 PDF Result:** Word-wrap works, but column width has no effect

[image: Word-wrap works, but column width has no effect]

---

**What I want is: a table with fixed width columns that has a working word-wrap**

Is this impossible to do on DomPDF?
Any workaround or 'hacks' that can help achieve this?

Or maybe I should start looking for other / better PDF generators?

*EDIT:*
I also found a lot of Github Issues on this, with no sign of the bug being fixed

- [Table cell width is not honored if content exceeds the specified dimensions #1017](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1017)
- [Table widths do not conform to css width attribute. #1253](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1253)
- [Fixed table layout ignored column widths #1432](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1432)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really an "answer", but my solution is switching to [Snappy PDF](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) (used the [Laravel Package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)).
Worked like a charm, I did not even change the HTML markups.

Answer (score 20):

I set width in % with table-layout:fixed and it worked fine

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, I solved it thanks to @Solonka's answer.

Example:

```html
<table border="1px" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:5%;">5%</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">10%</th>
        <th style="width:25%;">25%</th>
        <th style="width:60%;">60%</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
table{
      max-width: 750px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Width calculation in DomPDF is problem (td - in mm),
but the functional solution is use "border-box":

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```