# Laravel PDF Export : How to fit content?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, export, dompdf

I tried to export my datatables into the PDF using dompdf, however, not all the tables fit into the page so the content is cut, here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's my controller and blade.pdf

Controller

```
    public function exportpdf($id)
    {
        $submission = Submission::all()->where('id', $id);
        $sub = $submission->load('programStudies');
        $realizations = Realization::all()->where('submission_id', $id);
    
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('realisasi.pdf',['submission'=>$sub, 'realizations'=>$realizations]);
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

blade.pdf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{strtotime('now')}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr td,
        table tr th{
            font-size: 9pt;
        }
    </style>
    <center>
    @foreach($submission as $pengajuan)
        <h5>Laporan Realisasi Prodi {{$pengajuan->programStudies->implode('nama_prodi', ', ')}}</h4>
        <br>
        <br>
    </center>

    <p>Pengajuan {{ $pengajuan->tahun_akademik . ' Semester ' . $pengajuan->semester }}</p>
    <p>{{ $pengajuan->siswa . ' Siswa' }}</p>
    @php $fmt = new NumberFormatter('id_ID', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY) @endphp
    <p>{{  $fmt->format($pengajuan->pagu) }}</p>
    @endforeach
 
    <table id="detail-pengajuan-table" class="table table-striped w-100">
        <thead>
        <tr class="text-bold">
            <th rowspan="2">Nama Barang</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Gambar</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Jumlah Barang</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Harga Total</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Terealisasi (%)</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Keterangan</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-bold">
            <th>Pengajuan</th>
            <th>Realisasi</th>
            <th>Pengajuan</th>
            <th>Realisasi</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @php $fmt = new NumberFormatter('id_ID', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY) @endphp
        @foreach($realizations as $realisasi)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $realisasi->nama_barang }}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ 'storage'. str_replace('public', '', $realisasi->image_path) }}" alt="Gambar Barang"
                         width="250"></td>
                <td>{{ empty($realisasi->submissionDetail) ? 0 : $realisasi->submissionDetail->negotiation->jumlah }}</td>
                <td>{{ $realisasi->jumlah }}</td>
                <td>{{ empty($realisasi->submissionDetail) ? $fmt->format(0) : $fmt->format($realisasi->submissionDetail->negotiation->harga_total) }}</td>
                <td>{{ $fmt->format($realisasi->harga_total) }}</td>
                <td>{{ empty($realisasi->submissionDetail) ? '100%' : round((($realisasi->harga_total / $realisasi->submissionDetail->negotiation->harga_total) * 100), 2) . '%' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $realisasi->keterangan }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make the pdf to show all the content in the page, how to do and fix it?

Comment: try to use inline css instead of bootstrap css

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507279/dompdf-table-fixed-column-width-and-break-long-text

Comment: @RioSant My apologies for the late answer, but indeed it solved my problem.